# The player will not move where the camera is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I hold down the 'w' and move the camera the player will not move in the camera direction e.g if I go forward and move the camera to the left it would not go to the left but keep going forward, What are some possible ways to fix this. Player Movement Script

```
    public float movementspeed = 5.0F;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementspeed;
    float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementspeed;
    translation *= Time.deltaTime;
    straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translation);
}
```

}

and Camera View Script

```
    public float xMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;
public float yMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;

public float yMaxLimit = 50.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -50.0f;


float yRotCounter = 0.0f;
float xRotCounter = 0.0f;

Transform player;

void Start()
{
    player = Camera.main.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
    //xRotCounter = xRotCounter % 360;//Optional
    player.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);
}
```

}

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: I attached the first script to the camera, and the second script empty gameobject. I was able to move and rotate the camera. The moving is fine. It always move to the direction the camera is facing. What's the issue you are having?

Comment: Say I look to the left, and press 'w' it will not go left. the movement direction will not change with the camera, and doesn't matter what way I'm facing it will go in a specific way , like if I look forward and press 'w' and don't touch the camera, it will go straight, but if I turn the camera to look back and press 'w' it would go backwards

Comment: With the image you updated in your question, **don't** put a camera under the GameObject. Do it the other way around. Make that Player a child of the Camera then attach both script to the Camera which is now the parent Object of the Player.

Comment: I have the player as a child of the camera and both script attached to the camera and it now mostly move the camera around

Comment: I mean it moves the both but every time I faced up and move upward it drops the player and same if I look down.

Comment: I just noticed that it has Rigidbody. Disable the *Use Gravity* option.

Comment: Yeah, that work, thanks for helping

Comment: Nice and you are welcome. I think you should look into character controller too and thirdperson controller in Unity too. That's seems helpful for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use de camera transform to be able to do this. Something like:

```
public float movementspeed = 5.0F;
public Transform cameraTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementspeed;
    float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementspeed;
    translation *= Time.deltaTime;
    straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 movement = cameraTransform.Forward * translation + cameraTransform.Right * straffe;
    transform.position = transform.position+ movement;
}
```